# App hosted in IIS fails to access IBM WMQ SSL key

Tags: c#, iis, websphere, ibm-mq

SETUP:
So we have a domain service account user let's call it DOMAIN\testuser.
We've created a key to do a SSL secured connection to IBM MQ named as needed ibmwebspheremqtestuser.
We've set the app pool to run as DOMAIN\testuser.
We've given DOMAIN\testuser access to the location of the key.
The key exists and is configured correctly as we have 2 other WCF services hosted as Windows Service that use it as expected.

PROBLEM:
We have an IIS app that is using the same key and FAILS to access it with an error:

```
Process(6384.2) User(testuser) Program(w3wp.exe) Host(HOSTBOX) 
Installation(Installation1) VRMF(8.0.0.3)

The key repository could not be opened (channel 'CHANNEL.NAME').  

The key repository could not be opened. The key repository either does not
exist or has incorrect permissions associated with it. The channel is 
'CHANNEL.NAME'; in some cases its name cannot be determined and so is 
shown as '????'. The channel did not  start.  

Ensure that the key repository you specify exists and that its permissions 
are such that the MQ process involved can read from it. Restart the channel.
```

We've been banging our heads on this for 2 days now and checked all obvious issues (apppool identity, access to folders etc) with no luck.

Any advice is welcome.

Comment: Did the app use the IBM MQ .NET API in managed or unmanaged mode?

Comment: You have told us the name of your certificate, but you have not shown us the name of the key repository, nor told us any details about it. Could you say what it is and where it lives and how you told the w3wp.exe to use it, e.g. MQSSLKEY env var or something else?